# Bug Genie Bug Tracker Errors

Tags: php, debugging, issue-tracking

I have installed the latest Buggenie Bug Tracker - 3.2.7.1 for a new project of mine. But every time I want to add a bug to a milestone or click on a created issue to see the details I get errors. The main error I would like to squash is:

```
[13-May-2014 01:58:29 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getID() on a non-object in /home/me/public_html/bugtrack.domain.com/modules/mailing/classes/TBGMailing.class.php on line 552
```

That is this function

```
public function listen_viewissue(TBGEvent $event)
                {
                        $uid= TBGContext::getUser()->getID();
                        if ($this->getSetting(self::NOTIFY_ISSUE_ONCE,$uid))
                        {
                        $this->deleteSetting(self::NOTIFY_ISSUE_ONCE . '_' . $event->getSubject()->getID$
                        }
                }
```

debug mode has been turned on `protected static $_debug_mode = true;`

but there is no data in the log filethebuggenie.log even though I chmodded it to 777

I did [open an issue with buggenie](http://issues.thebuggenie.com/thebuggenie/issues/2378), but I think they are busy.

I tried a hack from [this forum](http://forum.thebuggenie.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1759), which stated:

> Add a line as the first line of the function:
>   `if (!$event->getSubject() instanceof TBGIssue) return;`

The error does disappear, but then I get:

> You have specified an issue that can't be shown This could be because
>   you the issue doesn't exist, has been deleted or you don't have
>   permission to see it
>   for all issues.

Comment: Will try a hack mentioned on their forum http://forum.thebuggenie.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1759 .

Comment: Does remove error, but I get `You have specified an issue that can't be shown. This could be because you the issue doesn't exist, has been deleted or you don't have permission to see it`

Comment: This is very off topic for Programmers.SE. [What questions can I ask here?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: What stackexchange site do you suggest @AdamZuckerman ? Another Buggenie question was asked here before. If someone think stackoverslow is better for example than please migrate it. I cannot myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error I could suppress as I mentioned. I used the hack I linked to in the initial post. But then I had permission issues. As soon as turned off the prefix in the project settings this permission issue disappeared. This solves my issues and hopefully they can avoid the error based upon my bug report in future releases.